# How do I change all values in a dataframe with a greater value?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I'm having a problem converting all values in my data frame that is greater than 1 to 2. Here's how the data frame has been set up (FYI, I'm using Python 2):

[screenshot of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLXfU.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
randomdata = DataFrame(np.where(randomdata>1,2,randomdata))
```

This should work. `np.where` is a conditional statement where you are checking if the value is greater than 1, and setting it to 2 if `True` and same value if `False`

It returns an np array, so you will have to convert it to a pandas dataframe again

Comment: Thank you so much! I keep replacing "DataFrame" with the name of my data frame :/